# Default font size doesn't change ChartJS

Tags: typescript, chart.js

I wanted to change the default font size of the following chart from default 40px to 14px. When I try setting Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize to 14 nothing changes. You can check the code below. Thanks in advance!

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 14;

let chart = new Chart(context, {
    type: 'line',
    options:{
        animation: {
            onComplete: function(e) {
              angularContext.onChartRendered(); 
            }
        },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 20,
                right: 40,
                top: 20,
                bottom: 60
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Bonello Distribution',
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
        }
    },
    data: {           
        labels: graphData.labels,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'My First dataset',
                data: graphData.values,
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                fill: false
            }
        ],
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to use is old V2 syntax while you are using V3, same for your title and legend options.

You can downgrade to version 2.9.4 by running `npm i chart.js@2.9.4` to make it work or you can change your defaults assignment to: `Chart.defaults.font.size = 14;`

Live example:

```js
Chart.defaults.font.size = 20;

var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This probably would've solved it for someone using the latest ChartJS, I'm using a lower version, however. Luckily I already found the issue, in another .ts file the default global font size was being set, meaning it was being overridden.